# Upvote and downvote buttons are not showing opposite one another

Tags: html, css

I am building a BlogApp and I am trying to make upvote and downbutton , Like Stack Overflow shows BUT my buttons are not showing `opposite one another`.

They are showing like:

template.html

```
<!-- Upvote button -->

        <span id="id_likes{{topic.id}}">
            {% if user in topic.likes.all %}
            <button name='submit' type='submit' value="like"><i  class="btn fas fa-sort-up fa-6x fa-lg post-buttons " ></i></button>
            {% endif %}
        </span>

<!-- DownVote button -->

        <span id="id_dislikes{{topic.id}}">
            {% if user in topic.dislikes.all %}
            <button name='submit' type='submit' value="dislike"><i class="fas fa-sort-down fa-6x"></i></button>
            {% endif %}
        </span>
```

When I use `div` instead of `span` then it shows like this:

It was showing border on buttons then I used:

```
<style>

button {
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    background: none;
}

</style>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]; you can use Stack Snippets (icon looks like `<>` in the toolbar) to do so.

Comment: Thanks for the suggesstion but I am using also some `javascript` to logic from the backend. BUT I will try now

Comment: Your sample seems to work fine

Comment: Yes but it is not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you check out the Fontawesome site for these icons ([up](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/icons?d=gallery&p=2&q=sort-up) and [down](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/icons?d=gallery&p=2&q=sort-down)), you'll see that they're designed as a pair, so that (when they're overlaid) the up arrow will be above the down arrow. If you use them separately, as you're doing, that means they're naturally high and low.

Basically, you've done nothing wrong - that's how these characters were designed to appear!

If you want to line them up, you'll need to manually alter the positions of one or both to get them as you want. You could use css `top` or `padding`, as you prefer.

Comment: Thanks for the Suggestion. I will try as you say, BUT Please see the updated question's snippets. It is not working for me

Comment: I don't see any change in the question that reflects what I put in my answer. As I said, what you're seeing (up and down not being aligned) is exactly how Fontawesome designed them - you're not doing anything. You need to add manual adjustment to line them up, if you want to use these arrow characters. (Note that you've not applied the `btn`, `fa-lg` or `post-button` classes to both icons, which may explain the horizontal disalignment when they're in divs.)

Answer (score 1):

> I have removed your dynamic code and added one css class.

```css
button {
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    background: none;
}
.btnOuter{
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<span>
    <button class="btnOuter" name='submit' type='submit' value="like">
      <i  class="fas fa-sort-up fa-6x fa-lg post-buttons" ></i>
    </button>
  </span>
  <span>
    <button class="btnOuter" name='submit' type='submit' value="dislike">
      <i class="fas fa-sort-down fa-6x"></i>
    </button>
  </span>
```

Comment: Thank You for Effort BUT I have solved it Now. It was because of `fa-lg post-buttons`, I was using in one button only. I removed from it and it is showing good